# Identify this airplane axle holder from Little Prince MOC

Tags: piece-information

[image]

Can anyone name the circled piece in this picture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this piece:

[Plate, Modified 2 x 4 Thin with Bottom Struts to Pins](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42608&idColor=9#T=C&C=9)

[image: part]

It comes in a few sets, usually as landing gear.

Comment: Yes that looks like the one. Unfortunately it looks like that might make the axles a bit weak. Do you know of one that doesn't have the pins at the bottom so a full axle can go all the way across?

Comment: @Craig I'm afraid not. It's one of the more specialty pieces from the Jack Stone era. I don't know of any similar pieces.